# How to move an image from asset library to an application specific private location?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

Here is the code snippet i tried:

```
[library    writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:self.checkInImage.CGImage metadata:self.metadata
            completionBlock             :^(NSURL * assetURL, NSError * error) {
        NSLog (@"Asset url = %@", assetURL);
         NSError *err;
        NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *jpgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.jpg", docDir];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                [fileManager moveItemAtURL:assetURL toURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jpgFilePath] error:&err];
                NSLog(@"error is %@", err);
    }];
```

I get the error as
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 262.)" UserInfo=0xb49a680 {NSURL=assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6FAC823A-33CB-489B-A125-714FBA5F0EE8&ext=JPG}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue:

1) I saved the file without metadata in some location, and stored its urlpath.

2) Then used the following piece of code to save the same file with metadata. Here fileURL is the urlpath obtained from step 1.

```
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateFilePathURL(NULL, (CFURLRef)fileURL, NULL);
// Creating Image source from image url
CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, NULL);

// This will be the data CGImageDestinationRef will write into
CFMutableDataRef data = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, CFSTR("public.jpeg"), 1, NULL);

BOOL success = (imageSource != NULL);

require(success, cleanup);

success = (imageDestination != NULL);
require(success, cleanup);

// Add the image contained in the image source to the destination, overidding the old metadata with our modified metadata
NSDictionary *metadata = someObj.metadata;
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imageDestination, imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)metadata);

// Tell the destination to write the image data and metadata into our data object.
success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination);

require(success, cleanup);

// Write the data into the url
[(NSMutableData *) data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
```

cleanup:

```
if (data) {
    CFRelease(data);
    data = NULL;
}

if (imageSource) {
    CFRelease(imageSource);
    imageSource = NULL;
}

if (imageDestination) {
    CFRelease(imageDestination);
    imageDestination = NULL;
}

return success;
```

Hope this helps. But I would like to upvote H2C03 for very helpful suggestions, which helped to arrive at this solution. Please help me how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Docs (and Google).](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) This error code corresponds to the `NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError` constant - i. e. you can't just use an `assets-library://` URL to move a file using NSFileManager. (The same is the case regarding `ipod-library://` URLs.) You have to use the AssetsLibrary framework to get the *data* of the file and then write it to a file using `- [NSData writeToFile:atomically:]`.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
[lib assetForUrl:theURL // the asset URL you have obtained, NSURL object
    resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        // get data
        ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef cgImg = [repr fullResolutionImage];
        NSString *fname = [repr fileName];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
        [data writeToFile:[@"BaseDirectory/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]
            atomically:YES];
        [lib release];
    }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // recover from error, then
        [lib release];
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Ideally I want to move the file, that means copy the file and delete the one in the assets. Is it possible?

Comment: @mobjug not at all. You can't directly access the filesystem location of a song, nor can you modify anything in the iPod library (well, I'm working on something with which it'd be possible, but that project of mine is not even close to ready...)

Comment: Even if my app created that file?

Comment: @mobjug if your app created the file, it's not in the iPod library.

Comment: Using AVAssetReader dint work. Here is the code snippet:       `AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
    AVAssetReader* reader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&error];` The error is Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open" UserInfo=0x14b8c6e0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x14b83090 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12847.)", NSURL=assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=94D22DB9-D1C7-4E5E-A869-3BEA5C1E70C5&ext=JPG}

Comment: @mobjug it means that... quote: "This media format is not supported".

Comment: Yes I get that. Is there a way to move a JPG image, (photos, the app created) from camera roll to a private location? or else is there a way to save the image along with its metadata in a private location instead of photo album, which the following code does:`ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:self.checkInImage.CGImage metadata:self.metadata
    completionBlock    :^(NSURL * assetURL, NSError * error) {}]`;

Comment: Thanks for the updated code snippet. The reason I cant use the above approach is I dont want to lose the meta data. My aim is resize the image chosen by the user (either from camera or from photo album) and save it to a private album  along with the exif meta data of original image(like location info etc).

Comment: @mobjug there's a `valueForProperty:` method on ALAsset for accessing metadata.