# save project video on the device's library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a video that is displayed automatically when the User enters this view. This video is a project directory but the User must have the option to save it in the library of your device. How can I do this?

Comment: whats does it mean, this video s project directory. could u more elaborate from where u r getting video. is it any url

Comment: The video is in the own project. In the folder assets

Comment: if it is folder assest then y u r saving it again locally. is it not odd

Comment: He's assets folder in my application that is not visible to a User. I need to save him in the library iphone.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12608668/2522603  hope it helps u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum) function:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoFileName, nil, nil, NULL);
```

Alternatively, you can use ALAssetsLibrary, or if you're targeting iOS 8, the [Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408).